# Quotient group by two isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

In the processes of studying some questions I suddenly realized something basic but weird. We have $\mathbb{Z}\cong 2\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}\ncong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It looks like isomorphism doesn't mean exactly the same, even in algebra problems. But I remember many tricks are based on that we regard isomorphic groups the same group (e.g. we may consider $G$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$), how can I check if those tricks are correct (or is it necessary to check)?

Comment: You should not expect something like $H \cong K$ implies $G/H \cong G/K$ to be true.  Quotients are sensitive to the "denominator" even above isomorphism type.

Comment: it essentially boils down to the cat you are working in: in your example the two groups are isomorphic, however, as you interpret them as subgroup the natural cat you are working in is the category of morphisms into $\mathbb{Z}$ where the two are clearly not isomorphic. However, I very much agree that any invariant should be unique at least up to isomorphism in an apropriate category

Comment: Basically a quotient depends not only on the isomorphism type of the "numerator" and of the "denominator", but also on the way that the "denominator" is embedded in the "numerator".

Comment: If two groups are isomorphic you always can think like they the same group, **how they are embedded in another group** is a completely unrelated issue.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The purpouse of the answers/comments is not only helping OP. It's also giving new points of view to other members of the site (even on elementary topics like this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Isomorphism is not equality and you can't expect it to solve all your problems magically.

**Long answer**

As I said in the comments:

"Basically a quotient depends not only on the isomorphism type of the "numerator" and of the "denominator", but also on the way that the "denominator" is embedded in the "numerator"."

More in general when there is a construction involving many objects it's possible that this construction depends not only on the isomorphism type of the objects but also on the interactions between these object.

*Trivial example:*

Let's say that two finite sets are isomorphic if they have the same number of elements. Let's consider the sets

$$A_1=\{1\}$$
$$A_2=\{2\}$$
$$B_1=\{1,2\}$$
$$B_2=\{3,4\}$$

Clearly $A_1\cong A_2$ and $B_1 \cong B_2$ but $A_1\cup B_1$ isn't isomorphic to $A_2 \cup B_2$ (because the interaction between $A_1$ and $B_1$ is different from the one between $A_2$ and $B_2$).

For some costructions the interaction doesn't matter like the cartesian product and the disjoint union: the deeper motivation as someone noticed in the comment is that these are what's called **universal constructions** in category theory (but at your level you don't need to know category theory).

Comment: Did you mean *expect* where you typed *except*?

Comment: Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Why the dislike?